# Dynamic 2d array in structure in shared memory c

Tags: c, linux, structure, shared

I would like to create a 2-dimensional array in a structure which I will pass on to the shared memory.

I've used malloc, but it doesn't work.

I use c language on Linux, and my code looks something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct my_data
{
    char **txt;
    int counter;
}*shared_data;

key_t shmkey;
int shmid;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    
    struct shmid_ds buf;
    
    shared_data = (struct my_data*)malloc(sizeof(struct my_data));
    
    shared_data -> txt = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char) * atoi(argv[2]));
    
    for(int i=0; i<atoi(argv[2]); i++)
    {
        shared_data->txt[i] = (char*)malloc(atoi(argv[3]) * sizeof(char));
    }
    
    if(shmkey = ftok(argv[1], 1) == -1) exit(1);
    
    shmctl(shmid, IPC_STAT, &buf);
    
    shared_data = (struct my_data *)shmat(shmid,(void*)0, 0); 
    
    if(shared_data == (struct my_data *)-1) exit(1);

    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't store pointers in shared memory. It doesn't work, except when you *really* know what you are doing. And then you probably know of better ways to things. To be honest, you are not actually storing pointers in shared memory, but it looks that that is your intention. There are a lot of other issues in your code, but it doesn't make sense to comment on those before you have a better way to represent 2d arrays. There should be a lot of articles on the web with better ways to handle arrays than using pointers to pointers.

Comment: C doesn't have a 2D array type.  You can either have an array of pointers to arrays, which doesn't work across different processes, or you can have an array of arrays, which doesn't work when both dimensions are dynamic.  Simplest is a 1D array and do the address arithmetic when accessing it.